# не выполняеться sql запрос

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

```
cur.execute(f"UPDATE gamers SET ar = ar-'{cena}', KukiCOIN = KukiCOIN+'{pokupka}' WHERE name LIKE '{igrock}'")
con.commit
```

Через базу данных смотрят сколько у человека "ar" и с помощью формулы высчитывает цену "KukiCOIN".

Данный запрос выполняется в DB Browser

Comment: Очень информативный вопрос. А ошибка какая?

Comment: Убрать одинарные кавычки вокруг числовых значений?

Comment: @strawdog не выдаёт ошибки, просто не выполняет запрос

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov выдаёт ошибку no such column:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commit - это метод , а не свойство

```
con.commit()
```